# Is there a command for windows PE to capture system specs?

Tags: windows

Is there a command for windows PE to capture system specs? I am looking to make a Windows PE script to capture the systems specs and import them to a xls file.

Answer (score 0):

The [systeminfo command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx).  For example:

`systeminfo /fo csv >specifications.csv`

Comment: awsome, thank you Jason. do you know of a good reference website for windows PE? this is my first time writing a script for windows PE and I'm guessing I'll need a bit of help later on in the script.

Comment: All the information you need to know about `Windows PE` is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx)